# Triangle with all reflex angles?

Tags: geometry, triangles, angle

I was thinking about how a triangle could have all reflex angles. it would look like a regular triangle but the inside would be the outside and the outside would be the inside.
[image: image of triangle]

Such a triangle would have three sides. The outside would extend infinitely without end so it can't be considered a side. Also the triangle would have three angles that are reflex. This would break some theorems about triangles. My question is, could this be a triangle? I looked it up and found no good answer but some places said a triangle cannot have any reflex angles.

Comment: The lines don't contain the space, so how can you describe the space as a triangle?

Comment: The orange space is the triangle. It has three sides and angles. Is it considered not containing the space because it is infinite?

Comment: @MRobinson I think under the modern definition of “contain”, and under OP’s definition of this triangle, it does contain the space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a fun question! There are a couple of ways you could answer it. If the triangle lives on the surface of a sphere, then 'inside' and 'outside' don't have the same meaning as they used to. There are other surfaces like that, too, like [the projective plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projective_space).

You're right that some triangle theorems break in these settings; for triangles on the sphere, the angles don't have to sum to 180$^\circ$, for instance.

Comment: Thanks, but would it be considered a triangle? Or maybe a special type or only in some instances?

Comment: Sure -- although the name is Tri Angle (three angles), the definition of a triangle is really just a polygon with three sides. Nothing about insides and outsides is included in the definition, so as long as you can define what a side is, you can have a triangle.

Comment: Is there a term for plane polygons like this? (Interior is infinite, finite number of sides, finite length of each side, simple.)